# Width issue in gauge amchart

Tags: amcharts

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div id="mychart"></div>    
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div id="content">Some content here</div>   
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to show my chart in full width. 
[image]
In below image can see there is chart show in small width. I think some padding  effect at them. 
I have draw the arrow which showing extra padding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to adjust a combination of the [`radius`](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/GaugeAxis#radius) in your axis and [`radius`](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/GaugeBand#radius) and [`innerRadius`](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/GaugeBand#innerRadius) in your bands to take up more room. You'll also need to adjust the [`marginTop`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmAngularGauge#marginTop), [`marginLeft`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmAngularGauge#marginLeft), [`marginRight`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmAngularGauge#marginRight), and [`marginBottom`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmAngularGauge#marginBottom) properties to re-center the chart due to the increased radii.

Here's an example:

```js
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "theme": "light",
  "type": "gauge",
  "marginTop": 0,
  "marginLeft": 50,
  "marginRight": 50,
  "marginBottom": -235,
  "axes": [{
    "radius": "70%",
    "topTextFontSize": 20,
    "topTextYOffset": 70,
    "axisColor": "#31d6ea",
    "endValue": 100,
    "inside": true,
    "tickColor": "#67b7dc",
    "startAngle": -90,
    "endAngle": 90,
    "unit": "%",
    "bandOutlineAlpha": 0,
    "bands": [{
      "color": "#0080ff",
      "endValue": 100,
      "innerRadius": "100%",

      "radius": "175%",
      "gradientRatio": [0.5, 0, -0.5],
      "startValue": 0
    }, {
      "color": "#3cd3a3",
      "endValue": 0,
      "innerRadius": "100%",
      "radius": "175%",
      "gradientRatio": [0.5, 0, -0.5],
      "startValue": 0
    }]
  }],
  "arrows": [{
    "alpha": 1,
    "innerRadius": "35%",
    "nailRadius": 0,
    "radius": "110%"
  }]
});

setInterval(randomValue, 2000);

// set random value
function randomValue() {
  var value = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
  chart.arrows[0].setValue(value);
  chart.axes[0].setTopText(value + " %");
  // adjust darker band to new value
  chart.axes[0].bands[1].setEndValue(value);
}
```

```css
#chartdiv {
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid #800;
  height: 275px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/gauge.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

Comment: You are the legend :)